# spring boot rabbitmq fail fast disable

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp

We are using spring cloud streams and the rabbitmq failfast seems to prevent start unless rabbitmq is running.

How can I disable this behaviour?

I note that at http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html#CO17-16 there is a property called lazy-connect="true".  Can this be set through an application.yml?

here is a section of the stack trace:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: rabbitmq-HA.service.vci
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:32)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:676)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:283)
```

I guess the exception is thrown all the way up and fails the spring boot startup.

Comment: It is `true` by default: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-amqp/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/amqp/outbound/AbstractAmqpOutboundEndpoint.java#L77. So, you "failfast" issue is somewhere else. Would be better to see the full StackTrace on the matter. That definitely should be a question of the `AmqpInboundChannelAdapter`

Comment: added a section of the stack trace

Comment: Well, that is a root of cause, but who performs that `connect`?

Comment: We need the full stack trace to see exactly what is trying to create the connection.

Comment: I will dig it up from the system logs

Comment: I just ran a quick test with a bad host and the app starts, emitting that exception every 5 seconds (the default recovery interval).

Comment: It could be that you are trying to use RabbitMQ before the context is fully loaded and started, e.g. from `afterPropertiesSet()`, a `@PostConstruct` method, or a `SmartLifecycle.start()` method. In which case, lazy connecting on the producer side won't help.